# Factoring out common setup code for a pytest fixture

Tags: python, pytest

I'm writing some tests with pytest and have what I believe is a simple question but am not sure the right way to do it. I have some code like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def obj1():
    ...setup object 1...
    return obj

@pytest.fixture
def obj2():
    ....setup object 2 ...
    return obj

def test_val_obj_1(obj1):
    ...some common boilerplate...
    output = some_function(obj1)
    assert output['important_key'] == some_values

def test_val_obj_2(obj2):
    ...some common boilerplate...
    output = some_function(obj2)
    assert output['important_key'] == some_values
```

For my two tests, the `...some common boilerplate...` and some_function() are the same, and so I would prefer to have this elsewhere. Do I just define a normal function to do this? Or do I need to do something specific with fixtures? I haven't totally wrapped my head about the "parameterized" fixtures in the docs and can't figure out if that's what I'm asking about or if that's a different use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parameterized` may help you, but it could depend on what is going on in boilerplate

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("obj,some_value", [(obj1, some_value), (obj2, some_value)])
def test_val_obj(obj, some_value):
    ...some common boilerplate...
    output = some_function(obj)
    assert output['important_key'] == some_value
```

Comment: Thank you. This might indeed work. What is the importance of the string that's the first argument to the decorator ("test_input, expected"). Can that be anything? In other examples I've seen online that string (roughly) matches the names of the arguments in the test being decorated, but not here (not that I would expect it to need to match if it's clearly decorating this function).

Comment: the naming convention for the parameters passed in is incorrect, you should fix that

Comment: @gammapoint no, as gold_cy mentioned above - it has to match with test args name

Comment: Hmm, in principle it seems like this should work but it's not for me. My objects that are defined in my `obj1` and `obj2` set up instances of a namedtuple, but when I send these to the test these objects don't have the attributes they are supposed to have (instead I get an error saying "'function' object has no attribute [my_attribute]". Is obj1 not actually being called and set up when it's defined like this?

Comment: Maybe my problem is the same as this : https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349

Comment: yes, looks so. almost 8 years passed after it was opened

Comment: Well, maybe I'll give up on it being solved by this afternoon then ;) In any case, for this particular instance I can create my objects through a dictionary of information passed to a constructor, so I'll pass in that dictionary to @pytest.mark.parametrize and then construct the objects in the test. Because that works, and you taught me something about this type of setup, I'm going to mark this as solved. Thank you!